# Unable to adjust font sizes and other params in matplotlib (scatterplot)

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, font-size

I spent hours researching this question on Google and found tons of answers. I actually have some pieces of code that work as expected. But today, I spent hours trying to change font sizes to no avail.

Here is my imports:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors  
from matplotlib import cm # color maps
```

Now the code to produce the scatterplot:

```
SMALL_SIZE = 0
MEDIUM_SIZE = 0
BIGGER_SIZE = 0

fig = plt.figure(figsize =(6, 4), dpi=120) 
axes = plt.axes()
plt.scatter(npdata[:,1], npdata[:,0], c=npdata[:,2], s=8, cmap=cm.coolwarm,edgecolors='black',linewidth=0.3, alpha=0.8)
plt.rc('font', size=SMALL_SIZE)          # controls default text sizes
plt.rc('axes', titlesize=SMALL_SIZE)     # fontsize of the axes title
plt.rc('axes', labelsize=MEDIUM_SIZE)    # fontsize of the x and y labels
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('legend', fontsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # legend fontsize
plt.rc('figure', titlesize=BIGGER_SIZE)  # fontsize of the figure title
mpl.rc('xtick', labelsize=0) 
mpl.rc('ytick', labelsize=0) 
cs = plt.contourf(yc, xc, zgridt,cmap='coolwarm',levels=16) 
cbar = plt.colorbar(cs)

plt.show()
```

I set everything to a size of zero, but whatever the size, nothing changes except the size of the font on the right bar.

Here is the plot:

[image]

I am wondering what is wrong in my code.

Comment: Would you add npdata sample that I can test your code?

Comment: Looks like I did not put my lines of code in the right order. "plt.scatter(...)"  should be below "mpl.rc('ytick', labelsize=0)". Still have other issues now, but that one is fixed. I can provide the full code, but it's a bit long and I would have to work on "minimum working version" that still shows the issue. Thanks you for your help!

Comment: Good luck. If any more questions, do not hesitate.

Comment: Vincent, why do you say "scatter" in the title, and in your comments, and eventually you show us a filled contour plot?

Comment: There is a scatter plot (see beginning of my code). It does not show up because the plt.scatter() line of code is not at the right place: it should be done after the contour plot. So the font size that won't change was one problem, and the scatterplot that does not show up, another problem caused by my mistake.

Comment: I fixed everything and happy to post the corrected code, with beautiful picture combining contour and scatterplots if someone is interested, with the right font size. My problem is the need to produce high-resolution, high-quality images to include in a book. And the default Matplotlib parameters work well for standard resolution, but I frequently have issues with large, high resolution pictures.